# Why do we take finite sums when defining the product of ideals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $I,J$ be ideals of ring $R$. The product of two ideals is defined by $\sum_{\text{finite}}ab : a\in I,b\in J$.

My question is why do we take finite sums when defining the product of ideals?

For example: Consider $R=\mathbb Z$ ,$I= 5\mathbb Z$ and $J=7\mathbb Z$ then
$IJ=\sum a_i b_j:a_i\in I,b_j\in J=\sum (5k)(7\ell):k,\ell \in \mathbb Z=\sum 35(k\ell)$

Even though $I$ and $J$ have infinite elements, why can't we add more elements from $I$ and $J$ in $\Sigma$?

Comment: If all we are given is that a set is a ring, we don't necessarily have a definition for what it would mean to add together an infinite number of elements.

Comment: Your initial question is ambiguous.  We allow finite sums because we want $IJ$ to be an ideal.  We don't consider infinite sums because, without a topology inherent in the ring, it wouldn't make any sense to take infinite sums.

Comment: Additionally, in general we only want to do the minimum required to satisfy any axioms, and an ideal only needs to be closed under $a,b \mapsto a+b$, and finite sums satisfies that. There is no need to include infinite sums, so we don't. If we had a metric laying around, and were discussing "closed ideals", we might want to talk about including infinite sums.

Comment: "why can't we add more elements". More as in infinite sums? That is not doable with some form of convergence. Which is not available in pure algebra. In pure algebra summation is always finite, there's no other choice. A set can be infinite, but not summation.

Comment: Maybe we donnot have the "limit" in the general rings.